# Using EventWaitHandle to ensure a single instance across multiple users

Tags: c#, user-accounts, single-instance, event-wait-handle

Collaborators have built a prototype using Processing that connects to a Sparkfun RFID reader, I think using a serial connection over USB. We've deployed the prototype into a number of trialists' homes and one common usage scenario I foolishly overlooked was user switching. Hence I am writing a wrapper that ensures only one instance of the prototype application is running across all users on the machine.

I’m testing out my first stab at this as a simple console app. Here’s the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/2590446/575530
        var users = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
        var rule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(users, EventWaitHandleRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
        var security = new EventWaitHandleSecurity();
        security.AddAccessRule(rule);
        bool createdStartup;
        using (var whStartup = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "Global/AaltoTokensAppStartupEvent", out createdStartup, security))
        {
            bool createdShutdown;
            using (var whShutdown = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "Global/AaltoTokensAppShutdownEvent", out createdShutdown, security))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Let other instances shutdown");
                whStartup.Set();
                Console.WriteLine("If other instances exist wait for them to shutdown");
                if (!createdShutdown)
                {
                    whShutdown.WaitOne();
                }
                whShutdown.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("Start tray app");
                var tokenProc = Process.Start(@"C:\Temp\FAMILY3_WIN\TokensApp.exe");
                Console.WriteLine(tokenProc.ProcessName);
                Console.WriteLine("Wait to see if another instance to tries to start");
                whStartup.Reset();
                whStartup.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("Shutdown if another instance starts");
                //if (tokenProc != null) tokenProc.Kill();
                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (process.ProcessName.StartsWith("javaw"))
                    {
                        process.Kill();
                    }
                }
                whShutdown.Set();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

(N.B. I know there are issues with this code around (1) killing Java processes that are not the running prototype and (2) there’s no code to respond to lots of instances starting simultaneously, just two at a time. But that’s not what my question is about.)

Testing this under a single user account works fine. I can start my app, it in turn starts the prototype, and if I start a second instance of my app the first one kills the initial instance of the prototype before the second one starts another instance of the prototype afresh.

But if I try doing this from two different user accounts it fails (silently). If I

1. Start an instance of my application it starts the prototype
2. Switch user
3. Start an instance of my application then it starts the
   prototype without my app from step 1 first shutting down the existing
   instance.

Can anyone see what’s wrong with my code? How should I use EventWaitHandle across several simultaneous user sessions on the same machine?

Comment: An event object is not the appropriate object here, it suffers from an unsolvable race condition.  Using a Mutex is boilerplate, it has a constructor that returns the *createdNew* bool that tells you that your process got there first.

Comment: Thanks Hans that is interesting. I think I'm relatively safe from race conditions in this case as the mechanisms by which a second app can start take time. I started using two mutexes but swapped to events, I'll explore some more.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you elaborate? EventWaitHandle has a constructor an overload that returns `createdNew` bool as well, but I think you are referring to the "Caution" section of the docs that note: "Other users may be able to open and use the event, including interfering with the event by setting or resetting it inappropriately." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-threading-eventwaithandle-ctor(system-boolean-system-threading-eventresetmode-system-string-system-boolean@)

Comment: @HansPassant The solution is to create an EventWaitHandleAccessRule and add that rule to EventWaitHandleSecurity _and_ call the overload with the `createdNew` _and_ `eventSecurity` parameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-threading-eventwaithandle-ctor(system-boolean-system-threading-eventresetmode-system-string-system-boolean@-system-security-accesscontrol-eventwaithandlesecurity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it always the way, minutes after writing a long question the answer leaps to mind!

I got the slash the wrong way around in the name of the EventWaitHandle. For example replacing the constructor call:

```
new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "Global/AaltoTokensAppShutdownEvent", out createdShutdown, security)
```

with this one:

```
new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, @"Global\AaltoTokensAppShutdownEvent", out createdShutdown, security)
```

fixes my problem.